# add new row to a table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

when I try to add a new row the fields in a row are as follows

```
$('#building').val()   $('#floor').val()
```

But I want to display the value it contains.

jQuery:

```
var newRow =
    $("<tr><td>$('#building').val()</td><td>$('#floor').val()</td><td></td></tr>");     
    $('#building-table').append(newRow);
```

html:

```
<select id="building" name="building" >
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
<input id="floor" name="floor" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="save" value="save" />
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You have to concatenate the return values of those functions with your HTML string, if you simply enclose it in quotes then it'll be treated as a string. JS behaves differently than PHP if you have experience with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this ?

```
var newRow = "<tr><td>"+$('#building').val()+"</td><td>"+$('#floor').val()+"</td><td></td></tr>";
$('#building-table').append(newRow);
```